# Op-amp with both inputs the same doesn't output zero

Tags: operational-amplifier, ltspice, single-supply-op-amp

In the picture below:

[image: Simulation]

We have exactly the same input at both + and - pins of the op-amp's input (in the above picture, In1 and In2 are identical).

Normally we must have a zero output all the time but in this case the low frequency component has been cancelled and the high frequency component has been amplified.

What kind of formula explains this phenomenon? I thought the high frequency should be cancelled since they are identical in input.

Comment: How are the voltage rails varying?

Comment: @JRE Whole circuit referrence is polluted with noise (50hz). But I though maybe full schmatic is irrelevant. Since we have all opamp pin's waveform.

Comment: The schematic appears chopped off and it is unclear whether your circuit does what you think it does. Please add full schematic.

Comment: @MathKeepsMeBusy I've found the answer and I've didn't delete the question. I thought maybe contribute. If you think this is bad tell me to remove it. Full circuit is here: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/626407/152533 But I think this is irrelevant to this question.

Comment: All real op-amps are not perfect.  There will usually be some non zero output when the inputs are shorted.  This could be documented as either an "input offset voltage" or an "output offset voltage".

Answer (score -3, accepted):

I have answered this question [before](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/623959/152533) in my own question.

Opamp's have high gain, then input's must be approoximately the same since they have high gain and visible difference between inputs causes output to becoming + or - rail. And the feedback are doing the job, it seems they are correlates inverting with none inverting input of amplifier through output of op-amp.

Answer (score 4):

I think you have a misconception of operational amplifiers.

They are **not** a mathematical block that does an analog computation like $$V_{out}=V_{in+}-V_{in-}$$

Instead it is more like:$$\frac{dV_{out}}{dt} \propto V_{in+}-V_{in-}$$

So, an *ideal* op-amp will have stationary (in general **non-zero**) output voltage, if the inputs are identical. In reality though, when the inputs are exactly the same (e.g. by shorting them), the internal input offset voltage of the amplifier will make them appear to be different to the op-amp. As a result, there will be a constant *change* of the amplifier output, as per the second formula above.

Comment: Thx for answer, My misconception was I though the input difference must be visible. But because of high op-amp gain the difference is (have to be) very small and need multiple zoom in plot of inputs.